# Best way to format number in SQl for display through Google Charts tooltips bar?

Tags: javascript, charts, format, google-visualization, tooltip

I have a SQL query that outputs data into an array, and I'm using it in google charts. When the number field is formatted as a raw number (e.g. 374000000) the chart and the formatting in my code works as it should. Tooltips show currency and commas show correctly (e.g. $374,000,000). Since I included the table below the chart, however, it is harder to use. So, when I format the numbers correctly in SQL and they show in the table (e.g. 374,000,000) then the google chart tooltip shows $4. I can't figure out what is happening. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
                <script  type="text/javascript"> 
                google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart'],
                callback: drawChart});

                function drawChart() {
                var tableRows = [];
                var results = document.getElementById('chart');
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(results.rows, function(row) {
                var tableColumns = [];
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(row.cells, function(cell) {
                var cellText = cell.textContent || cell.innerText;
                switch (cell.cellIndex) {
                case 0:
                tableColumns.push(cellText.trim());
                break;

                default:
                switch (row.rowIndex) {
                case 0:
                tableColumns.push(cellText.trim());
                break;

                default:
                tableColumns.push(parseFloat(cellText));
                    }
                  }
                });
                tableRows.push(tableColumns);
                });

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(tableRows);
                var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
                     {negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, pattern: '$###,###'});
                    formatter.format(data, 1);      
                var options = {
                      slices: { 0: {offset: 0.2},
                                1: {offset: 0.2},
                                2: {offset: 0.0},
                                3: {offset: 0.1},
                                4: {offset: 0.0},
                      },     

                title: 'Nice chart', 
                titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 28},
                 bar: {groupWidth: '70%'},
                    chartArea: { backgroundColor: { fill: '#F0F8FC', opacity: 100 }},
                    fontSize:12,
                    legend:  { position: 'right', textStyle: { color: 'black', fontSize: 12}},
                     tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                      is3D: true,

                    };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_dev'));


                chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: what if you use google's [table chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) instead of the table you're using?

Comment: It appears the Google table chart forces a user to hard code values, and the method I'm using receives my values live from the database.

Comment: no, it uses a data table you can load, just like any other chart. you could even draw the table chart using the same data table as the pie chart

Comment: WhiteHate. I've looked at some of the things you've suggested to others and confess, you're clearly an experienced and skilled developer, far beyond my skill set. But, I'm not following you. When I go to the google table chart page the values are hard coded. I see no way of getting my SQL query into that vs the way I'm doing it currently. If there's some example that I'm not seeing, and you're feeling generous, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw a table chart, using the same data table as the pie chart.

here, where you create the data for the pie chart...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(tableRows);
```

then draw the pie chart...

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_dev'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

you can also draw a table chart...

```
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_dev'));
table.draw(data, options);
```

just be sure to include the `'table'` package in the load statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'table'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: Thank you for that WhiteHat. The TableChart is drawing. Still brings the original problem. In SQL when I "Format(revenue, 'currency') AS MyRev" the value in MY table shows what I ultimately need (e.g. $2,476,098). The value in the TableChart, however, shows as NAN and the actual Chart is blank. If I "Format(revenue, '#,##0') AS money"  (e.g. 2,476,098 with no $ symbol), the TableChart shows $2 and the tooltip shows as $2 also. If I "Format(revenue, '###0') AS money"  (e.g. 2476098 no commas, no $ symbol) the TableChart and Chart draw correctly, and tooltips draw perfect $2,476,098.

Comment: I get it now. If I don't treat the number in SQL, the number comes out raw and I format it in the GoogleChart script with the correct formatting and voila! Thank you WhiteHat!